# undefined method `each' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5741c0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, image-uploading, nested-attributes

I try to upload a file, with using CarrierWave, and the Image model is polymorphic. But i got the error as in the title, so here is my models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    enum image_type: {icon: 1, title: 2, regular: 3, slider: 4}
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

end
```

and the _form.html.erb :

```
<div class="control-group">
   <%= simple_fields_for :images do |image| %>


     <div class="controls">
        <label class="control-label">Hizmet Büyük Resimi</label> 
        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
          <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt=""/></div>
          <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
          <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Resim Seç</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Değiştir</span>
              <%= image.input :image, input_html: { type: :file, class: "default"}, wrapper: false, label: false %>
              <%= image.input :image_type, :as => "hidden", :input_html => { :value => 2 } %>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Sil</a>
          </div>
        </div>


     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

and the service_controller "create" action:

```
def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)

    if @service.save
      if params[:images]
        params[:images][:image].each do |i|
          @image = @service.images.create!(:image => i, :imageable_id => @service.id, :image_type => params[i][:image_type])
        end
      end

      flash[:notice] = "Hizmet sayfası başarıyla oluşturuldu!"
      redirect_to admin_services_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Hizmet sayfası eklenirken bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz!"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

ErrorMessage:

```
undefined method `each' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5741c0>

Rails.root: D:/Projects/TorkGarage/website/torkgarage

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/admin/services_controller.rb:19:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yN62eOMu2gTrNIWgs27XBiA3uxIAGVgTGt4ywTSm3lKn4kEqG2Ka+3IdaqvSpRQrOPVkBBiuWLl1l5jx5fEUWw==",
 "service"=>{"service_name"=>"Rot - Balans",
 "service_description"=>"sdsad asdas&nbsp;",
 "meta_keywords"=>"adas da"},
 "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1",
 "images"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xa5741c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/mehmet/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20150430-6992-8dc0q8.png>,
 @original_filename="Layer-6.png",
 @content_type="image/png",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[image]\"; filename=\"Layer-6.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">,
 "image_type"=>"2"},
 "button"=>""}
```

So, what's going on wrong in this situation?

Comment: .each is used for array but here in parameters, there is no array, it is a hash. so it is throwing this error.

Comment: @Kushal so, instead of .each should i use ".each do |key, value|"?

Comment: change `params[:images][:image].each` to `params[:images].each` which should loop on UploadedFile objects

Comment: @MrYoshiji i tried this too, but this time i got "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to iterate through an array of images but your params only have one image so the fix is replace:

```
params[:images][:image].each do |i|
  @image = @service.images.create!(:image => i, :imageable_id => @service.id, :image_type => params[i][:image_type])
end
```

with

```
@image = @service.images.create!(:image => params[:images][:image], :imageable_id => @service.id, :image_type => params[:images][:image_type])
```

Comment: You are still calling `.each` on a UploadedFile object ... which will also raise a `NoMethodError`

Comment: Yes this doesn't work either, is the solution using key - value pair?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the effect of use copy and paste, updated the answer

Comment: Yes this solved the problem, but i have another question, on the same form there will be more file uploads and each of them are related to the same model but their image types are different. So that time will be using .each work? It's a nested form, and i need to have more than one image_type... @Aguardientico

Comment: Yes, but you will need to change the html input to be an array, I mean instead of `name='image'` you should use `name='image[]'`

Comment: @Aguardientico well in my situation, there will be 3 single uploads and 1 multiple upload, i know it sounds bad, but as for the different image_types my solution is going to be like that. So for multiple images you are right i can handle with "name = 'image[]'", but there will be singles also.